# Best way to query an array of structures using BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

What is the best way to design a GATT characteristic/service to allow querying an array of similar objects?

For example, lets say I want my device to present the set of all network neighbors (discovered through a mechanism beyond the scope of this question).

With a traditional management interface, I would probably use a `get-first`/`get-next` interface to walk the list.  Or I'd have one call to get a list of identifiers and then a `get` call to get the details corresponding to one identifier.

But BLE GATT doesn't seem to have direct support for this.

I could make a characteristic return the entire array of objects, but that has the potential to be very large.

I could also make a characteristic to get a list of identifiers, but then how would I get the details for one object?  Maybe write it to a characteristic that will cause the device to send the results via a notification/indication?

I don't think it would be right to define a characteristic that, when read, returns the details of an object previously specified by writing to a different characteristic.  I'm sure this could be done, but it doesn't seem to fit within the spirit of how GATT is expected to operate.

Comment: You might find this walk through of some help: https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/ . Also, looking at the official services might give you some ideas on how you could solve this: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/

Comment: Thanks for the tip about official services.  There are a lot of them, but I did notice that the Binary Sensor Service (https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=468620) is using my second idea - write a command to one characteristic and get a response via an indication on another characteristic.